# Active Border Property stopped working in chrome all of a sudden

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My website has borders on many objects using border= activeborder 1px solid and it was working fine till last week on all the browsers. Now it has stopped working just on Chrome (Works on all other browsers). I haven't changed anything in the style sheet and have checked many times but it still does not work for some reason. Here's a sample of the code. If I change activeborder to gray 1px solid it works. Why so ? some kind of google update ?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
<div>
    <table style="width: 90px; margin-top: 27px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 30px;">
                Latest News
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: activeborder 1px solid; padding: 10px" align="left">
                <a style="color: #666666;" href="" target="_blank">one</a>
                <br />
                <a style="color: #666666;" href="" target="_blank">two</a>
                <br />                    
                <a style="color: #666666;" href="" target="_blank">three</a>
                <br />                    
                <a style="color: #666666;" href="" target="_blank">four</a>
                <br />                    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My chrome browser updated to version 32 last week.

Comment: Mine too, is there a way around this ? I have this border style on atleast 20 different pages and I hope I don't have to change on all these places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activeborder is not a standard css colour name. Using a standard name e.g. gray, or #666 or rgb(50,50,50) should work.

They were included as CSS2 system colours, but are now deprecated (an apparently now don't work). My testing shows that:

```
background-color: ActiveBorder;
```

... does work in IE11 and FireFox26 but not in Chrome32. Try seeing if it works in Quirks mode.

Find and Replace is your friend if you want to use css3 standard colors ;)

And ... ahem ... you should be defining your css in a stylesheet, not inline rough idea:

```
table.grid {width: 90px; margin-top: 27px;}
.grid td {border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px 10px; text-align: left;}
.grid a {color: #666}
```

but I'm sure you knew that and were only doing inline for the example ;)

Comment: ha ha, the above is just an example. Most styles are defined as  classes in style sheet. Thanks anyway.